# Leaving internship early for health reasons

Tags: internship, quitting, health, mental-health

I've been working at an internship for three months now out of a 12 month internship. These past three months have been some of the most grueling and difficult months in a long time. My boss is a self proclaimed perfectionist dictator and is very bad about getting angry when I don't produce the results she wants. I wake up every morning feeling sick, I don't eat nearly enough and I have found myself feeling depressed and crying often. A lot of people are telling me I just need to stick through it, but my girlfriend says that I need to be happy. I'm positive I won't work in the marketing world again, so my question is:

**How do I evaluate whether I should stay or leave this internship?**

Comment: I changed teh questions for you so to avoid the question getting closed an unanswerable. We can;t tell you what you should do, but we can tell you the methods for making that determination. Feel free to rollback, but be aware the questions will likely get closed.

Comment: As a side note, don't write off all of marketing just because of this job. It sounds like the majority of your problems have to do with your boss and the work environment, which are not going to be the same at every company.

Comment: Some people will tell you to keep pushing through no matter what, but I think situations like this, where your boss has a lot of power over you, just an intern, having that mindset can make you extra vulnerable to treatment a person shouldn't have to endure.  So quitting is always an option, but it should only be a last resort.  You should see if you can talk to people, maybe even your boss, and come up with a solution to make it bearable for you first.  In this day and age, experience is #1 for getting you work, and so quitting now, even if you can afford to, could still affect you later.

Answer (score 3):

Only you can determine what factors are the most critical to you. I can however help provide a structure for the types of things you need to consider in making the choice about what to do.

First, this is an internship, are you getting college credit for it? Are you willing to throw that credit away if so?

Next, do you have other professional work experience that will help you land a job in the field you want to go into? Are you getting any knowledge from this job that will help you land a better job in the future? In other words, is there something to be gained from continuing that you can't get any other way.

Many people find their early bosses to be unreasonably harsh because they are not used to the pace of the workplace or nature of how business works in terms of deadlines and clients, etc. So as an intern, one the most critical questions you need to find the answer to is: Is this boss unusually bad or more typical of what is actually expected in the workplace?  If you can talk to people who are not your peers about this behavior of this person and see if they think that he/she is as unreasonable as you think. If possible, talk to people outside your workplace such as professors or parents or other people of a generation older than you are. Do not at this point ask others at your workplace. Try for an objective, outside source who can hold the information in confidence.

Next consider your own reaction to this. One of my early bosses was horrible nmicromanager (and I can still say that more than 30 years later) who pushed me really hard and insisted on following his exact process even if I thought there was a better way and checked in on me constantly. I did not however let it make me sick. Are there things you can gain from learning to cope better in the workplace? There are always going to be people who are difficult to deal with. There are always going to be stresses. Can you make learning to deal with those stresses a part of what you gain from this internship? Have you sought professional help for your depression?  That said, and only you can make this determination, is the situation so bad that you need to get out now? Or can you stick it out until you land another job? Learning to deal with workplace stress is one of the most critical things you gain from an internship.

IF you leave now, before getting another job, are you going to set a work pattern of running away from problems. There are times when it becomes the easiest thing to do. I am not saying that leaving one or two times is bad, but you need to be careful that it doesn't become your default response.

Answer (score 1):

A job is where you exchange your time for money, so you can use the money for something you would not be able to do yourself using said time.

Example:

> I work one hour to have the money to pay someone to clean my house for three hours. For obvious reasons, that is a winning move, because I could not clean my house myself for three hours in the one hour I gave up. I come out ahead.

So to come out ahead, you need to earn *more* than what you lose by working.

We cannot help you with prioritizing your life. But you need to ask yourself: With the money you earn, can you buy back what you lose and still have money left? Because if you don't, working that job does not make sense.

So in your specific case, do you get enough money to buy happiness and health?

You can certainly buy a pretty shallow (or deep but we likely aren't talking about *that* amount of money here) imitation of happiness, but you won't be able to buy health.

**You need to change something.** Maybe quit, maybe find another solution by asking a different question here. But simply proceeding on the way you are on now will not work.

Comment: Yes you need to change something, it might not be the job, it might be how you react to the job.  Or it might be the job. Only the OP can make that determination.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, health is always your primary concern. If you aren't enjoying the work you're doing or if your work is affecting your health in a negative I think it's time to call it quits.

That being said there are other options and things to consider.

1. What exactly is your boss doing that is having a negative effect on your health and well being?
2. Can you talk to HR or someone else in your company who you can trust about your current situation?
3. Is money an issue? Are you currently experiencing financial problems and do you need this job to help pay the bills?

Like others have said, you know the situation best and so only you can really make a decision about this.